# How to Increase the Number of Contour Lines (Denser) for a Specific Region?

Tags: plotting

I'm struggling to increase the number of contour lines shown on this graph, and preferably there are more contour lines between x+y==0 and x+y==2.

`ContourPlot[x + y, {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, ContourStyle -> Red,  ContourShading -> False]`

Neither MaxIteration nor Plotpoints seems to change the graph; there are always 5 lines shown.

Edit: with `Contours` I can make more equally spaced contours, but how can I make it such that it's twice as dense inside the region of x+y==0 and x+y==2 ?

Comment: You could try  `Contours -> 10` or `Contours -> 20` etc... and see if this does what you want.

Comment: If you look at the docs for `Contours`, you should notice that you can specify particular $z$-values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is use `Mesh`.

```
ContourPlot[x + y, {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, ContourStyle -> Red, 
 ContourShading -> False, Contours -> 5, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, x + y], Mesh -> {Range[1, 2, .1]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red]
```

Or

```
ContourPlot[x + y, {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, ContourStyle -> Red, 
 ContourShading -> False, 
 Contours -> Join[{-1, 0}, Range[1, 2, .1], {3, 4}]]
```

[image]

Comment: useful options for this special case `PlotPoints -> 2` and `MaxRecursion -> 0`

Comment: The `mesh` functions are powerful! The document for it in ContourPlot is quite limited, so thanks for showing how these can be done!